# My OpenGraph action is always showed in English instead of my translated language

Tags: facebook, translation, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I created a Facebook OpenGraph action (in English), got it approved, translated all the phrases to Spanish and "approved" all the created translations on the Facebook localization dashboard. In addition, I already set the locale metatags of my object urls to es_ES. Still the action always showing in English language.

The translation progress bars still showing at 0% progress even when I have translated all the strings and approved all of them (I am admin for the Facebook app) many times.

Already read all the Facebook localization docs. Anybody got through the same process and know what error may I have made? I don't know what more to do.

Thanks you all.

Comment: where you able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the localized js URL:

From: //connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

To: //connect.facebook.net/LOCALE/all.js

Comment: I mean, I'm using //connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js, that is the language I want the action to be showed in (spanish).

Comment: When using test users, I performed an action and the notification was indeed translated. But still the action on the users feed is in English.

Any ideas?